# Nested Count query

Tags: sql, count, subquery

I need some help for a query that outputs something like this:

```
CityName
CITY A
CITY B
CITY C
CITY A
CITY A
CITY A
CITY C
```

From this example, the count of each city is: CITY A = 4 , CITY B =1 , CITY C = 2

How can I add the ***(nested) Count*** of each CityName next to it so the output looks like this:

```
CityName   CityCount
CITY A              4
CITY B              1
CITY C              2
CITY A              4
CITY A              4
CITY A              4
CITY C              2
```

Any feedback would be more than appreciated!

---

I have the following table with the following fields:

**CitiesList**  --> *CityName* | *Town* | *Date*

An output of the table **CitiesList** looks like this:
*CityName*   |   *Town*      |      *Date*
CITY A      TOWN B      Jul 10, 2012
CITY A      TOWN D      Jul 10, 2012
CITY B      TOWN C      Jul 11, 2012
CITY C      TOWN C      Jul 11, 2012
CITY D      TOWN A      Jul 12, 2012
CITY D      TOWN C      Jul 13, 2012
CITY D      TOWN B      Jul 13, 2012
CITY E      TOWN C      Jul 13, 2012
.....

I want to add an extra field (*TownCount*) to this output with the number of times each TOWN appears in a time spam (Jul 10-Jul 13 in this example). The output should look like this:
*CityName*   |   *Town*      |      *Date*      |      *TownCount*
CITY A      TOWN B      Jul 10, 2012         2
CITY A      TOWN D      Jul 10, 2012         1
CITY B      TOWN C      Jul 11, 2012         4
CITY C      TOWN C      Jul 11, 2012         4
CITY D      TOWN A      Jul 12, 2012         1
CITY D      TOWN C      Jul 13, 2012         4
CITY D      TOWN B      Jul 13, 2012         2
CITY E      TOWN C      Jul 13, 2012         4
.....

Answer (score 4):

You provided no details on what kind of system you are using but in SQL you can use:

```
select t1.cityname, t2.CityCount
from yourtable t1
left join
(
    select count(*) CityCount, cityname
    from yourtable
    group by cityname
) t2
    on t1.cityname = t2.cityname
```

## See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a71c/1)

Based on your edit, it looks like you want to do the following:

```
select t1.cityname, t1.town, t1.date, t2.TownCount
from yourtable t1
left join
(
    select count(*) TownCount, Town
    from yourtable
    group by Town
) t2
    on t1.town = t2.town
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2911e/2)